# spark Dataframe column transformations using lookup for values into other Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to transform dataframe's multiple column values by looking up into other dataframe.

[image]

The other dataframe on the right will not have too much rows, say around 5000 records.

I need to replace for example field_1 column values to ratios like field_1,0 to 8 & field_1,3 to 25 by looking up into right data frame.

So eventually it will be filled like below:

[image]

**Option 1** is to load & collect the look up dataframe on left into memory as broadcast it as boadcast variable. A Map of Map can be used I believe and should not take too much of memory on executors.

**Option 2** is join the lookup data frame for each column. But I believe this will be highly inefficient as the number of field columns can be too many like 50 to 100.

Which of the above option is good? Or is there a better way of filling the values?

Comment: I would suggest you to go with option one of broadcasting map of lookup dataframe

Comment: You should try both and benchmark them, since the code doesn't seem too-nontrivial, but I also suspect option 1 will be much faster. A 5000-row map is pretty tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for option1, e.g.:

```
val dfBig : DataFrame = ??? 
val dfLookup : DataFrame = ???

val lookupMap = dfLookup
  .map{case Row(category:String,field_values:Int,ratio:Int) => ((category,field_values),ratio)}
  .collect()
  .toMap

val bc_lookupMap = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(lookupMap)

val lookupUdf = udf((field1:Int,field2:Int) =>
  (bc_lookupMap.value(("field_1",field1)),bc_lookupMap.value(("field_2",field2)))
)

dfBig
  .withColumn("udfResult", lookupUdf($"field_1",$"field_2"))
  .select($"primaryId",$"udfResult._1".as("field_1"),$"udfResult._2".as("field_2"))
```

Comment: thank you for responding. I am new to spark environment. I also figured out that we can broadcast a small DataFrame and then make a broadcast join. Need to see how this would look. E.g: https://henning.kropponline.de/2016/12/11/broadcast-join-with-spark/

Comment: There would be too many joins I guess but because each operation is on individual column (narrow transformation) will Catalyst optimized it to perform in single pass like explicit map operation on DataFrame I am wondering.

Comment: Just curious as to which of these methods would be more performant? The lookup udf or the broadcast join. I understand that the broadcast join is an internal spark implementation, but if the lookup udf just involves key-value "map.get", I don't see how that would be not as performant as its join counterpart. Any comments?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth - On same example, if I need to do contains then what would you suggest? for example my cell value contains "I found 0 and 2" should get replaced with "I found 9 and 5". Thank you so much