# How to perform a lookup and replace operation on spark large data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes:

[image: trips]

[image: lookup table]

and I want to replace the pulocationid and dolocationid to zone names of the lookup table based on the locationID, and the trips data frame would fairly large, so how could I perform this operation, I get some idea from [spark Dataframe column transformations using lookup for values into other Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952766/spark-dataframe-column-transformations-using-lookup-for-values-into-other-datafr) but I'm not sure whether it's the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity to use PySpark SQL joins.

Also I'm assuming you want to join pulocationid to locationid, the below example will also work with dislocationid

```
trips.join(lookup_table,trips.pulocationid ==  lookup_table.locationid,"inner").select(<columns you want to keep>)
```

More examples here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-join-explained-with-examples/%3famp=1

Comment: Thank you! It seems I misunderstanding how join actually function. But further I want only join the Zone column from the look up table, is it only achievable by using the select operation? it's a large table contains many columns so it would be a very hard coding

Comment: If you want to keep only a few columns then "select" would be more efficient to write. You also have the option to "drop" if you are only removing a couple of columns

Comment: thank you! it seems select and drop is a powerful combination.